# NSMutableAttributedString not working

Tags: ios, swift

I created a xib file with UIlabel. I would like to add line spacing to UILabel. I wrote the code below but it does not change the line spacing between lines. ( I tried with attribute editor and it didnt solve)
What is the problem?

The code is working for other VC but not for this xib.

```
import UIKit

class TBLCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let id = "TBLCell"

    @IBOutlet var lbl:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var view:UIView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        let font = UIFont(name: "MuseoSansRounded-300", size: 18.0)!
        self.lbl.font = font
        self.lbl.numberOfLines = 0

    self.selectionStyle = .none


    }



    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func topViewDesign() {
        self.lbl.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        self.view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
        self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        self.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 217/255, green: 217/255, blue: 217/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        self.view.layer.borderWidth = 1

            //add line spacing to lbl
        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (self.lbl?.text)!)
        var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.lineSpacing = 5
        attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (self.lbl?.text?.characters.count)!))
        lbl.attributedText = attrString


    }

}
```

//   cellForRowAtIndexpath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TBLCell.id) as? TBLCell


        if cell == nil {
            cell = TBLCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: TBLCell.id)
        }

        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell?.backgroundView = view
        cell?.backgroundColor = .clear

        let rows = self.sections[indexPath.section]
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell?.topViewDesign()
            //Question Row
            let question = rows[0]
            cell?.lbl.text = question
        }else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            //Translation Row
            cell?.bottomViewDesign()
            let question = rows[0]
            cell?.lbl.text = question
        }
        return cell!
    }
```

Xib file
[image]

Comment: Fix your code, because the snippet you posted will not even compile.

Comment: Change numberOfLines value to 0, default is 1 of UILabel.

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar yes it is 0 but still not working.

Comment: Where is called `topViewDesign`? Where is changed `lbl.text`? Because from your example, a `style.lineSpacing = 5` with just "Label" as text, that's gonna be difficult to see.

Comment: @Larme top ViewDesign is called in other VC at cellForRowAt indexPath. lbl.text is changed dynamic in plist file.

Comment: @risa8 - you need to double-check that the code is actually being called. I just ran a quick test, using *your* cell class (changed the font name), and called `topViewDesign()` on every-other row (from cellForRowAt). Here is the result: https://imgur.com/a0z0jVt  --- as you can see, the line spacing *is* changed.

Comment: hmmm... is it possible you are setting `.lineSpacing = 5` and the font you are using already *has* a line spacing of 5, so you don't see a difference? Try changing it to 25, and see what you get: https://imgur.com/Ly7RQ20

Comment: It is changing the uicolor of lbl.textColor so i guess it is being called..... :(

Comment: I set it 25, 50 but getting same result.

Comment: Show an image of your actual screen output?

Comment: I assume you are setting the text of the label ***before*** you call `topViewDesign()` on it?

Comment: Could you show `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? Also, with `NSAttributedString`, I wouldn't be messing with `label.font` and `label.textColor` that are for `label.text` and not really for `label.attributedText`.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the paragraph style of your label, and *then* setting it back to plain text. Swap the order:

```
    let question = rows[0]

    // set the text for the label
    cell?.lbl.text = question

    // *then* set the style
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        //Question Row
        cell?.topViewDesign()
    }else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        //Translation Row
        cell?.bottomViewDesign()
    }
```